# Symbol Import to Illustrator from pdf file

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Does anyone know why in the pdf file, I can see the graph really good in the first picture but when I import it into Illustrator, it results in the squared symbol like the second picture below?

First picture:

[image: First picture]

Second picture:

[image: Second picture]

Comment: The symbols are either a font or a symbol created in different file and not embedded in final pdf.

Comment: Thanks, but when I used Inkscape, it works normally

Comment: Inkscape use preview items in place of regular ones if the "source" is missing.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestion? I generate this plot by R programming language

Comment: You can flatten the transparency and change outlines to paths. You can do that either in Adobe acrobat or optimize pdf using ghostscript

Answer (score 1):

The symbols are either a font or a symbol created in different file and not embedded in final pdf.
Some programs (like inkscape or scribus) can use "preview" when opening file. 
If the symbols are vector they can be flatten or changed into paths and objects. It can be done with Adobe acrobat (sometimes require adding 1% white transparent object) or with various scripts for pdf optimization.